Where to store SSL cert and private key files with what permission?
I am currently writing my own server with nodejs for a little rest api. I read in the private key and certificate with the fs.readFileSync() method. Those are then used to open an https server.
But I dont believe the location of the private key and certificate in the project to be secure. Some google searches said I should put key and cert in /etc/ssl/[private/certs] respectively. But with the ownership of these files being root:root my own server can't access those files anymore. I am a bit confused.
How do I store those files securely while my server still has access to them?
I am on Ubuntu 22.04.

The server shouldn’t have access to them only the user of the certificate.

@Ramhound: the server is the user of the certificate

@SteffenUllrich - So service is ran by root? That’s not very secure.

@Ramhound: Based on what the OP writes the server does not run as root - and can thus not set the permissions of the private keys to be only readable by root. Apart from that it is fairly common that server start as root to read private keys and bind to privileged ports, but then drop the root privileges for security reasons.

There is no secure way to store the private key in your current server design - which requires the private key to be an unencrypted file and thus makes it possible for everybody with the same rights as the server to access the private key.
There are various more secure designs, like:

Private key is encrypted and the decryption key is fed to the server on startup in a secure way. Or the private key is stored in some external key management system (KMS). This replaces one problem with another, in that now the decryption secret must be secured or the authentication credentials for the KMS. But in some cases this is the easier problem.
Server starts with higher privileges to read the key but after loading the key into memory drops the privileges. This is a common design with web servers.
Privilege separation: Internet facing server does not directly operate on the key, but instead let some other program do the needed operations on the key (like signing). The other program is running with different privileges or even in a different environment. This is the approach with smartcards or HSM: private key stays on the hardware and can not be extracted from this, but smartcard can creates signatures using the key

As you can see, these solution can be significantly more complex compared to what you currently do. If you really need to implement a more secure way mainly depends on the actual threats you face and what the impact might be.

Thank you very much for your answer! I will mainly look into the second option. I don't think I face any big threats. It's a gameserver on a vserver, but I also use it to learn hence my desire to make it at least somewhat "right".
